# Always Throwing Exception

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've crated simple registration using Mysql connection in Vb.net but I am always getting exception error while form is loading but after closing dialog my registration form is loading and working properly. Where I am doing mistake? Anyone can help me with below code?

```
Public bool2 As Boolean = True
    Dim mysqlconnection As MySqlConnection
    Dim mysqlconnection3 As MySqlConnection

    Private Sub frm_registration_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If IO.File.Exists(Environ("SystemRoot") & "\SMPregistration.ini") Then
            bool2 = False
            f_main.Show()
            Close()
        Else
            mysqlconnection3 = New MySqlConnection
            mysqlconnection3.ConnectionString = "Server=Server;Port=3306; user id=User; password=Password; database=mydatabae"
            mysqlconnection3.Open()
            Using ds1 As New DataSet()
                '########################################
                Dim sqlquery3 = "SELECT ID, Registration, Used, CPU FROM activation"
                Using command3 As New MySqlCommand()
                    Using myadapter3 As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                        Try
                            command3.Connection = mysqlconnection3
                            command3.CommandText = sqlquery3
                            'myadapter3.SelectCommand = command3
                            myadapter3.Fill(ds1, "activation")
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MsgBox("Error! No connection with database.", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
                        End Try
                    End Using
                End Using
                Dim br1 As String = GetCPUid()
                For Information As Integer = 0 To ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                    If ds1.Tables(0).Rows(Information).Item(3).ToString <> br1 Then
                    Else
                        bool2 = False
                        f_main.Show()
                    End If
                Next
            End Using
            mysqlconnection3.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sure just a type-o, but your database name renamed for this sample is missing "s"...  you have "databae"

Comment: Can you post the actual message content of the exception message?  Its an object so you may need to look at inner text / message settings.